# Toggle react components

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When I open a component I need to close all other components. On click they render a list

```
class ParentComponent extends Component{ 
  constructor(props){
   super(props)
   this.state= {...}
 } 

   render(){
      return(
         <DropDown />
         <DropDown />
         <DropDown />
        )
   }
}
```

Each DropDown component has its own state to manage open/close on click event. How can i make sure all components are closed except the one i click on ?

Comment: You could move the state up to the parent component and manage their open/closed state in there so that when Dropdown is opened, all others are closed.  I can't really think of any other way to do this off the top of my head. :\

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately, you need to keep track of which Dropdown component is "active" in the ParentComponent's state. I can think of a few ways to toggle the active state of each Dropdown component, but the high level explanation would be to pass a function from the parent component as a prop into the dropdown component that will call `this.setState` on the parent's state upon the user opening/closing the dropdown. You can then define another prop on the Dropdown component that "deactivates" it. Finally, in your parent component, conditionally apply the "deactivate" flag to the Dropdown components that you want to be closed based on the state.